# Display a non-editable field in a Django formset

Tags: python, django

I have a model

```
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    # ... few fields ...
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(.., auto_now_add=True, ..)
```

I'm using FormSet to create few objects.

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
```

```
ApplicationFormSet = modelformsetfactory(..)
```

Field "pub_date" is added automatically for newly created objects.

Also I'm using FormSet to update my instances. This is shown in the view:

```
def applications_list(request):
    applications = Application.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ApplicationFormSet(request.POST, queryset=applications)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

    formset = ApplicationFormSet(queryset=applications)

    return render(request, 'applications/applications_list.html', {'formset': formset})
```

In template I'm using a table with:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
and
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
```

to show all objects and update it.

But I can't bring to content "pub_date" because it's a non-editable field, which cannot be added to form (formset).

How can I add "pub_date" (non-editable) together with other fields of forms?

In other words, how can I output a set of fields from one object that will only be displayed as information about previously entered data (without the possibility of editing it, as "pub_date"), and output the other part of the fields as a form for editing (for example "name"), using only the FormSet?

Answer (score 0):

First point is about the `pub_date` field in your models. If you want to add the current time or date, you can use of `datetime` builtin library in python and set it as a default value for `pub_date` field.

Look at the codes:

```
import datetime
...
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Also you can use of another cool option in django that is `from django.utils.timezone import now` and replace it like this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
pub_date = DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)
```

Pay attention to `blank=True` if you set it `False` and user pass it empty, your program get an error because `blank=True` can make it as an optional model field in your program.

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I don't want the creation date of the object to be editable, but I need it to be displayed when the form is output for editing in the FormSet.